# Angular function with two parameters having Error: [$parse:syntax]

Tags: javascript, parsing, angularjs, indexing, syntax-error

The full error is:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' not a primary expression
```

The piece of code causing the error is:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">

    <input type="submit" ng-click="delete({{item.itemId}},$index)" value="delete">

</div>
```

The function actually works for previous items but breaks when I try a new item to my item array. The problem child appears to be the comma, but I do not know what to do.

Comment: please post your model `items`

Comment: Thanks I found that the error had to do with a function on my factory.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to wrap `item.itemId` in `{{}}`. Just do:

`ng-click="delete(item.itemId, $index)"`

You only need to wrap in braces when using Angular's templating system - the braces tell Angular to replace the value. In this case, the value of ng-click is an expression that is evaluated (within the scope of your controller) when a click event occurs.

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/655/)</kbd>

Comment: The error was actually completely different, but +1 for some extra information. Actually, I recently realized that neither of these things need to be passed in, as you can pull both the object of interest and the index from the this variable.